# Scipy installation through easy-install on windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, blas, atlas

I try to install Scipy on windows 7 I followed guide to install ATLAS/BLAS from here http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/install/index.html but after I run `easy-install scipy` I have an error:

```
C:\Users\t>C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe scipy
Searching for scipy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Reading http://www.scipy.org
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=27747&package_id=1
9531
Reading http://new.scipy.org/Wiki/Download
Best match: scipy 0.11.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.11.0.zip#md5=
40b700ddde9ddab643b640fff7a9d753
Processing scipy-0.11.0.zip
Running scipy-0.11.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tszyro~1\appdata\
local\temp\easy_install-z05lfr\scipy-0.11.0\egg-dist-tmp-zxl8pc
Running from scipy source directory.
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1425: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1434: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
   warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1437: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
error:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
```

I don't know what should I do at the moment. During BLAS/ATLAS installation I did not have any warnings it seems it installed ok, although not sure how to check it now.

Comment: I had the same problem, it would be nice if anybody had a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose any of the prebuilt binary installers from http://www.scipy.org/install.html. Much easier than manual building and installation.

Comment: Yes, true, with Enthought windows world much better. I hope they will do now something for android